# Watchos2 not released yet... what are our options for existing apps to release?

Tags: ios, watchos-2

We currently have a version of our app with a watchos component.  We have modified the app to work with iOS 9 and watchOS 2.  With the delay in releasing watchOS 2, are we delayed in releasing our app?  Can we submit by just removing the watch component, and re-adding it later?  Going back to the previous watch OS code would be a terrible option for us since we made many refactoring decisions that changed how things were implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. For the time being you can remove/comment code related to WatchOS and release the app on AppStore.

Once WatchOS is released you can uncomment/add the code and release it again.